# What are the command line arguments for Node.JS

Tags: node.js

Node.JS accepts several command line arguments to optimize the application, for example `-expose-gc` will expose the garbage collector within the app.

**Where can I see the full list of command line arguments?**

I already tried a Google search of *site:nodejs.org "-expose-gc"* but no relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a manual page for node installed on your system (`man node`).  This lists the command line arguments including the V8 arguments like `--expose_gc`.

The uncompiled manual page (still quite readable) is [in the official github repo](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/doc/node.1).

Comment: Thanks. I tried `node --help` on windows but it doesn't display all the opts, but `man node` works on Linux.